# How to Filtering Categories from Autocomplete jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, autocomplete, filtering

I apologize before to repeat questions is already exist.
my question is filtering categories that I needed or hide some categories,
here is my array

```
var data = [
  { label: "London", category: "Area" },
  { label: "Muenchen", category: "Area" },
  { label: "North London", category: "City" },
  { label: "East London", category: "City" },
  { label: "West London", category: "City" },
  { label: "South London", category: "City" },
  { label: "Lorem London", category: "Hotel Name" },
  { label: "Ipsum East London", category: "Hotel Name" },
  { label: "Hello Hotel", category: "Hotel Name" },
  { label: "Mega Hotel London", category: "Hotel Name" }
];
```

and my output

[image]

I want hide for Category **"City"**. How to create it? Any suggestion?

Here is my source code https://jsfiddle.net/dedi_wibisono17/ae5wk1ex/2/
Thank you very much

Comment: Why do you want to "hide"? Deleting those lines it's more simple.

Comment: hi @eapo 
actually the data is exist in the API, the data is quite a lot and I only display a part of it. That is the reason why I did not delete it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the desired result by using `grep` to easily filter the array. Reference:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/

Ex:

```
var filteredData = $.grep(items, function(item,index) {
  return item.category !== 'City';
});
// original code below + change to reference grep'd array
$.each( filteredData, function( index, item ) {
    var li;
    if ( item.category != currentCategory ) {
        ul.append( "<li class='auto-complete'>" + item.category + "</li>" );
        currentCategory = item.category; //buat category
    }
    li = that._renderItemData( ul, item );
    if ( item.category ) {
        li.attr( "aria-label", item.category + " : " + item.label ); //buat item
    }
});
```

Forked jsFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ppa8em56/

Comment: Hi @Stevangelista oh thank you it's very useful for me. Oh i think it will using filter. thank you for the reference anyway